# Is it possible to get the range coordinates of an event object?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am developing Google Spreadsheet Addon with GAS.
I want to add function that you set A1 notation and the Addon filter onEdit event according to it.

For example, when you set A2 to the Addon,
onEdit event fire only when A1 is edited.

I want to convert A1 notation to Range object.
For example, I want to convert A2 to { columnEnd: 1, columnStart: 1, rowEnd: 2, rowStart: 2 }.

I think it is possible to use [getRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getRange(String)) method, but it doesn't work well.

Do you know any good methods for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update based on Op's comment:**

> When onEdit event fire, I can catch range information of the event
> object. It contain 4 informations (columnEnd, columnStart, rowEnd, rowStart).

```
function onEdit(e) {
   const actR = e.range;

   const actR_cords = {
      columnEnd: actR.getWidth()+actR.getColumn()-1,
      columnStart: actR.getColumn(),
      rowEnd: actR.getHeight()+actR.getRow()-1,
      rowStart: actR.getRow()
}   
}
```

**References:**

- [getRow()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getrow)
- [getColumn()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getColumn())
- [getWidth()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getwidth)
- [getHeight()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getheight)

Comment: Thanks for your comment. When onEdit event fire, I can catch range information of the event object. It contain 4 informations (columnEnd, columnStart, rowEnd, rowStart). So I think that I can get the 4 informations from A1 notation. Is it difficult??

Comment: why do you need 4 information? you can define a cell with only two coordinates: row, column. You can then do `getRange(2,1)`

Comment: There is also a pattern that I want to convert A1 notation about range. For example, A1:A10 etc...

Comment: okay.. so you want to find the coordinates of `A1:A10` ?

Comment: sorry.. I add description for this issue to POST! I want to filter onEdit event with setting A1 notation freely.

Comment: @Jamm I updated my answer. Now it gives the coordinates as you defined them in the question: `{ columnEnd: 1, columnStart: 1, rowEnd: 2, rowStart: 2 }`